# Xcode Instruments CoreGraphics Leak

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

Xcode Instruments is saying that I have a CGColor Leak.

- Responsible Library: CoreGraphics
- Responsible Frame: CGTypeCreateInstance

The stack is tracing it back to "Main" and the code below is highlighted as the error.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([PDCAppDelegate class]));
    }     
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you all!

Comment: Everything on the main thread will eventually trace back to there. The question is, what's between the top of the stack and there?

Comment: Hi Ken, when I look at the detail rollup of the leak, the only item highlighted in black is "Main". My understanding was that the greyed out items are beyond my control. Is that not correct?

Comment: Well, the other point is that the responsible frame is just where it was allocated. You need to examine the history of the object to see if other parts of the code retained it but failed to release it.

Comment: OK ill dive more into it. Obviously new to memory mgmt. Have an app without ARC. Should I start by trying to convert my entire project to ARC, or should I try and track this stuff down manually?

Comment: ARC is good and I recommend it, although it's not a panacea. Keep in mind that ARC doesn't help with non-Objective-C memory management like Core Graphics. As a matter of taste, with things like this I personally always like to solve the mystery to my satisfaction first and then consider switching to a different way of doing things. At the very least, it will be a valuable learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, your PDCAppDelegate, or something it owns, is creating a CGColorRef and failing to release it.